# Bundler can't find torquebox-web gem when runing script/console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, torquebox

I'm trying to get a Rails 2.3 application working with Bundler/Torquebox on a Linux (Redhat) server. The application works correctly through JBoss, but won't let me start up a console. I get the following error when running `jruby script/console`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "torquebox-web":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    torquebox-web (2.3.1)

  In Gemfile:
    torquebox (= 2.3.1) ruby depends on
      torquebox-web (= 2.3.1) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

When I run `jruby -S bundle update` it tells me it is using all the right versions of the gems, but the console still won't work.

I'm running Rails 2.3.18, Torquebox 2.3.1, and Bundler 1.3.5. Also worth noting is that this works correctly on my Windows development machine and on any Rails 3.2 applications (using `jruby script/rails console`). Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec jruby script/rails console`

Comment: @Simon Good idea; I hadn't thought of that, but unfortunately that has the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jruby script/console` apparently needs JRuby in the `PATH` to work correctly. If that isn't added to the `PATH`, that command will pick up the system Ruby (or whatever else might be in `PATH`).

To fix this, I was able to run the following commands:

```
export PATH=$JRUBY_HOME/bin:$PATH
jruby script/console
```

As Simon pointed out, using `bundle exec` before the `jruby` call is a good idea too:

```
bundle exec jruby script/console
```

If you don't want to run the `export` command every time, add that environment variable where you set all of your other environment variables.